# JBOSS+SPRING RequestParam URL ENCODING

Tags: java, spring, jboss

I have an endpoint

```
@RequestMapping(value="/register")
public String register(@RequestParam("p") String p) {

}
```

The value passed to `p` parameter is actually an encoded URL. However, when it reaches my endpoint, it's automatically converted to the decoded form. I want it to stay in the encoded form.

Is there a way to do it? Perhaps some configuration?

Comment: Why don't you simply re-encode it. It's not even Spring that decodes it, it's the servlet API.

Comment: what kind of servlet container do you use? tomcat or something else?

Comment: I use JBOSS.  in the client side, the value passed to p is hello%E2%98%BA, which is the encoded version of "hello☺".  When it reaches my endpoint, it becomes garbage like  helloâ?º.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @JB Nizet. Most convenient way is:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/register")
public String register(@RequestParam("p") String p) {
    p = URLEncoder.encode(value, "utf-8");
}
```

where `utf-8` is just for example. Actual encoding depends on your case.

Sure it is not automatic, but not needed to reconfig servlet context on any servlet server of deployment.

To force JBoss encode url in `utf-8`, you can try add to you server configuration:

```
 <system-properties>
        <property name="org.apache.catalina.connector.URI_ENCODING" value="UTF-8"/>
        <property name="org.apache.catalina.connector.USE_BODY_ENCODING_FOR_QUERY_STRING" value="true"/>
 </system-properties>
```

Comment: well this is what happens: in the client side, the value passed to p is hello%E2%98%BA, which is the encoded version of "hello☺".  When it reaches my endpoint, it becomes garbage like  helloâ?º